# Adapt rows height to first element with fixed column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table whith a fixed column and overflow-x on the rest. It works well but the rows height doesn't adapt to the fixed values...

Add a fixed height in the CSS resolve it but I can't do that because my first element are coming from a database and I don't know how big they are.

Anybody have an idea how to fix that problem ?

Here's my code : http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/1371/

```css
.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 5px 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
th:first-child {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table id="consumption-data" class="data">
    <thead class="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Month</th>
        <th>Item 1</th>
        <th>Item 2</th>
        <th>Item 3</th>
        <th>Item 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="results">
      <tr>
        <th>Jan too much content here</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Feb</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163 content here is ok</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mar</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Apr</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>May</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Jun</th>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
        <td>3163</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>...</th>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write JavaScript that will put equal heights to all rows based on first row height. Or on the server side you can check how long is the string on the first column and render table rows with specific class (double-height). However I would suggest to give enough width to the first column.